# normalization of values in python np array gone wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, data-science

I have a matrix of floats shaped (3000, 9).
Across 1 line, there is 1 ''simulation''.
Across columns, for a fixed line, there's the contents of the ''simulation''.

I want that for each simulation, the first 8 columns to be normalized to the sum of the 8 first columns.
That is, the first column's entry (for one fixed line) to become what was before, over the sum of the first 8 columns (for that same fixed line).

A trivial task, but I get from a nice, correct, graph (non-normalized), something totally unphysical when plotting with plt.scatter.

The last column of each line is what we are going to use for the x-axis to plot the first 8 columns (the y values).
So one line will represent 8 datapoints for 1 fixed value of x.

The non-normalized graph:
https://ibb.co/Msr8RVB

The normalized graph:
https://ibb.co/tJp7bZn

The datasets:
non-normalized: https://easyupload.io/oat9kq

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


non_norm = np.loadtxt("integration_results_3000samples_10_20_10_25_Wcm2_BenSimulationFromSlack.txt")

plt.figure()
for i in range(non_norm.shape[1]-1):
    plt.scatter(non_norm[:, -1], non_norm[:, i], label="c_{}".format(i+47))
plt.xscale("log")
plt.savefig("non-norm_Ben3000samples.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')

norm = np.empty( (non_norm.shape[0], non_norm.shape[1]) )
norm[:, -1] = non_norm[:, -1]

for i in range(norm.shape[1]-1):
    for j in range(norm.shape[0]):
        norm[j, i] = np.true_divide(non_norm[j, i] , np.sum(non_norm[j, :-1]))

plt.figure()
for i in range(norm.shape[1]-1):
    plt.scatter(norm[:, -1], norm[:, i], label="c_{}".format(i+47))
plt.xscale("log")
plt.savefig("norm_Ben3000samples.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Do you see what went wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Can you post a sample of `non_norm`?

Comment: @not_speshal, what do you mean by a sample of non_norm? Thanks. non_norm is extracted from the .txt I uploaded at: https://www.file.io/deleted. Edit: the file has been deleted by unknown reasons.

Comment: What about this link: https://easyupload.io/oat9kq. Does it work?

Comment: can you check the output of `print(non_norm[:10])` before plotting? When I run your code, I get a whole lot of `np.nan` values.

Comment: From what I know, plt.scatter ignores the np.nan's values. print(non_norm[:10]) returns no NaN's ...

Comment: You realise when you're normalising a row that has just one value and 7 zeroes, the value becomes 1 and the rest of the row is 0? This is likely why your plot is messing up. Plot each column one by one (normalized and non-normalized) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the reason. I have some very small, non-zero values of my columns at the very far LHS of the graph, and these get blown up by the normalization. I was biased by my previous plots because there all my columns were 0 for the far LHS of the plot. Can you please post your comment as an answer? Thanks

Comment: Yes, a silly mistake of mine. I didn't realize it. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're normalising a row that has just one value and 7 zeroes, the value becomes 1 and the rest of the row is 0? This is likely why your plot is messing up.

For example, the plot for the first column looks like this before and after normalization:

[image: before]

[image: after]